# Swift 3: display the Json data inside arrays

Tags: ios, json, swift

I work with Swift3. 
I am having Json data like below.
I got all data except the street key value pair and in this street should be treated as array or dictionary.

But I still don't understand how to get the data for this street key value pair ?

Here is my code for getting data in Json url

```
var guestShippingAddressModel : GuestAddress?

func shippingaddressURL(guestAddressApi: String) 
{
    print(guestAddressApi)
    let url = URL(string: guestAddressApi)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil { print(error!); return }
        do {
            if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                self.guestArrayCount = jsonObj.count
                self.guestShippingAddressModel = GuestAddress.init(dict: jsonObj)
                if self.guestShippingAddressModel?.firstName != nil{
                    self.addressSelected = true
                    self.selected = false
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

here is my table view data

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let dict = guestShippingAddressModel
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = "\((dict?.firstName)!) \((dict?.lastName)!)"
            cell.addressLabel.text = "\((dict?.street)!) \((dict?.city)!) \((dict?.region)!) \((dict?.postCode)!)"
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\((dict?.telephone)!)"


struct GuestAddress {

    var id : Int
    var region : Any
    var regionId : Any
    var regionCode : Any
    var countryId : Any
    var street : [GuestAddressStreet]
    var telephone : Any
    var postCode : Any
    var city : Any
    var firstName : Any
    var lastName : Any
    var email : Any
    var sameAsBilling : Any
    var saveInAddressBook : Any

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let arr = dict["street"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
        {
            var filterArr = [GuestAddressStreet]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(GuestAddressStreet(dict: obj))
            }
            self.street = filterArr
        } else {
            self.street = [GuestAddressStreet]()
        }
        self.id = dict["id"] as! Int
        self.region = dict["region"]!
        self.regionId = dict["region_id"]!
        self.regionCode = dict["region_code"]!
        self.countryId = dict["country_id"]!
        self.telephone = dict["telephone"]!
        self.postCode = dict["postcode"]!
        self.city = dict["city"]!
        self.firstName = dict["firstname"]!
        self.lastName = dict["lastname"]!
        self.email = dict["email"]!
        self.sameAsBilling = dict["same_as_billing"]!
        self.saveInAddressBook = dict["save_in_address_book"]!
    }
}

struct GuestAddressStreet 
{
    var zero : Any
    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        self.zero = dict["0"]!
    }
}
```

Here is example of my json data:

```
{
    "id": 843,
    "region": "fdgfgdfgdfg",
    "region_id": 12,
    "region_code": "fdg",
    "country_id": "India",
    "street": [
        "No: 14; 8th cross street"
    ],
    "company": "Test Company",
    "telephone": "1234568",
    "postcode": "43",
    "city": "dfgdfgdgdgdr",
    "firstname": "fdsfdsfsf",
    "lastname": "s",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "same_as_billing": 0,
    "save_in_address_book": 0 
}
```

Comment: `["No: 14; 8th cross street"]`: That's an array, not a dict. ` self.zero = dict["0"]!` should crash, no? So do instead `init(array : [String]) {self.zero = dict[0]!}`

Comment: then how to get the string in table view @Larme

Comment: I had added my code in table view @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let streetArr = dict["street"] as? [String]
    {
        var filterArr = [GuestAddressStreet]()
        for obj in streetArr {
            filterArr.append(GuestAddressStreet(dict: obj))
        }
        self.street = filterArr
    } else {
        self.street = [GuestAddressStreet]()
    }
```